# Considerations for switch mode power supply with microcontroller and sensors

Tags: microcontroller, adc, switch-mode-power-supply, low-power

I'm fairly new to this forum and the entire field of electrical engineering. I have a microcontroller (Atmega328P) project that includes a current sensor and several radios (900Mhz-2.4ghz). It is battery powered from a lithium 36V nominal battery. I was looking at using the LM46002 simple switcher from texas instruments to power my project.

However, as I delve deeper into the design I'm not sure what switching frequency to use, and also what supporting circuitry I might need such as bypass capacitors and the such to help smooth the output. I will be making ADC measurements and the same question applies to the ADC circuitry - what considerations will I have to make with the design to best power my project and get the most accurate measurements.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: most ti switchers come with an eval board which has a PDF somewehere on their side with schematics and bill of materials. Also, many datasheets actually contain a "demo circuit" and  a lengthy info on what caps etc to chose.

Comment: Yep, chaper 9 in the LM46602 has a quite extensive tract about what components to chose for the application circuits on p. 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many IC suppliers, TI amongst them, produce Evaluation boards for their chips. That's the case for the LM45602, too, and it's usually a good idea to use these to inspire your own design.

What's more important: the datasheets usually come with "demo" schematics. In this [case](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm46002.pdf), there's three of them on p. 24; chose the one you need:

1. V_out >= 3.3V [image: >3.3V]
2. V_out < 3.3V [image: <3.3V]
3. and an "all the bells and whistles" circuit [image: bells&whistles]

Chapter 9 goes into great detail about what components to chose for this circuit.

Also, the extensive "Detailed design routine" explains how you chose switching frequency etc. Usually, you try to go as high as feasible, to be able to filter out the noise with a simple low pass filter (as built by source impedance and the capacitors from V_out to ground), but if your ADC sampling rate happens to be close to that, you might actually want to chose something else. But that would be pretty advanced design.

Now, a switch mode power supply can, with reasonable effort, only ensure some limits on noise/ripple on the power line. Luckily, there's a lot of measurement data in the datasheet, too. For example, the step response oscilloscope measurement for the 5V output case of the first circuit:

[image: load transient]

It's up to you whether the noise in the figure is tolerable.

What is often done in applications which measure or generate sensitive analog signals:

Use a switch mode power supply to generate a voltage slightly above the needed one, and then use a linear (often, low drop) voltage regulator to get the final voltage. That can easily eliminate a lot of the switching noise, and you often get a better accuracy by using decent-quality linear regulators cheaper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will use the data sheet for my design now. I saw it had a table of values for different output voltages and switching frequencies etc. So I think what I may do is use a lower switching frequency to increase efficiency and then use an LDO to reduce noise for more accurate readings. Without the LDO, would the noise after a filter and bypass capacitor be acceptable in general for a circuit? Aka do I really need an LDO or would the smoothed output be good enough to provide accurate readings?

Comment: There's sadly no "in general" for this case – it really depends on the signal you want to observe, how you observe it and the mechanisms with which power line noise couples into your observation.

Answer (score 0):

While Marcus has already given a great answer, I'll add a few things.

Since you are powering this off a battery, efficiency of power conversion is another factor you should look at. TI provides a software called the [SwitcherPro Desktop](http://www.ti.com/tool/switcherpro) which helps you design a power supply based on your considerations using their TPSXXXXXX DC-DC converters. Their online WEBENCH tools are also quite handy. I usually start with the SwitcherPro to narrow down a list of converters based on the input and output requirements, then look for their availability and pricing with my local supplier and then finally zero in on a controller.

Very often these converters have a PSPICE data model along with a file that does the transient simulation in TI's own [TINA-TI](http://www.ti.com/tool/tina-ti) software (which is a free download). The simulation would give you a fair idea of what kind of ripple you can expect at varying levels of inputs and loads.

While using an LDO on the output can certainly reduce the ripple to a large extent and improve your ADC accuracy, do note that their efficiency depends on the lowest input voltage needed to achieve a regulated output. You also need to consider an inherent drop in voltage across them (which is why Marcus mentioned designing your Switcher to a slightly larger voltage than needed). Perhaps something like [this one](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS796) may help. There are LDOs that have very low dropouts (within a few tens of millivolts) but these are more expensive.